# Java morse code application continued (gui)

Tags: java, user-interface, morse-code

i have a couple questions about my program. I am attempting to create a java gui program that takes the user input (eng) and then translate it to morse code. I need to go through characters of the input one characters at a time. How do i do this? i know you need to use charAt(i) for this but i really don't understand how to apply it to this program. Also, how do i convert StringBuilder to string, to put in the label? thanks a lot for your time. heres what i have so far.

```
    Map<Character,String> charToCode = new HashMap<Character,String>();
    charToCode.put('A', ".-");
    charToCode.put('B', "-...");
    charToCode.put('C', "-.-.");
    charToCode.put('D', "-..");
    charToCode.put('E', ".");
    charToCode.put('F', "..-.");
    charToCode.put('G', "--.");
    charToCode.put('H', "....");
    charToCode.put('I', "....");
    charToCode.put('J', ".---");
    charToCode.put('K', "-.-");
    charToCode.put('L', ".-..");
    charToCode.put('M', "--");
    charToCode.put('N', "-.");
    charToCode.put('O', "---");
    charToCode.put('P', ".--.");
    charToCode.put('Q', "--.-");
    charToCode.put('R', ".-.");
    charToCode.put('S', "...");
    charToCode.put('T', "-");
    charToCode.put('U', "..-");
    charToCode.put('V', "...-");
    charToCode.put('W', "..-");
    charToCode.put('X', "-..-");
    charToCode.put('Y', "-.--");
    charToCode.put('Z', "--..");




   text1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
       String input = text2.getText();
       label.setText(input);
     }
   });

     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        String input = text1.getText();
        label.setText(charToCode);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all characters in the string with a for-loop. For the conversion from `StringBuilder` to `String`: [`StringBuilder.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29) returns the content of the `StringBuilder`.

```
public String parseCode(Map<Character , String> morseAlphabet , String input){
    StringBuilder morse = new StringBuilder();

    //iterate over the indices of all characters in range
    for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++)
        if(morseAlphabet.get(input.charAt(i)) == null)
            //the character has no valid representation in morse-alphabet
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown sign: \\u" + (int) input.charAt(i));
        else
            //append the correct morsesign to the output
            morse.append(morseAlphabet.get(input.charAt(i)));

    return morse.toString();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `else` constitute the for loop as a multi-line statement, therefore invalid without closing braces?

Comment: @xTrollxDudex nope, that's a single-line statement. if it wasn't you'd need more than 1 semicolon

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. I'm used to the standard at my organization with enclosing brackets so I am not very familiar with that :P

Comment: @xTrollxDudex just a matter of style. I know plenty of people who prefer to always use brackets

Comment: @Paul   Thanks a lot, both you guys! 2 questions; what is the morseAlphabet? I dont have that declared anywhere in my program and could you explain each line and its purpose because i really want to learn this thoroughly(i understand most but some lines are obscure). Also, do i delete the string builder i currently have in my program? thanks.

Comment: @reckless this map: `Map<Character,String> charToCode` is the morsealphabet (you can use it as parameter for the function).

Answer (score 1):

For a string given by the user, `string`, you'd convert to uppercase to match the characters in the HashMap, and iterate through the chars.

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    String s = charToCode.get(string.charAt(i));
    if (s == null) throw new RuntimeException ("No character found");

    mc.append(s).append(' ');
}
```

To convert the StringBuilder, `mc`, to a String, use `StringBuilder#toString()`